# Notify In A Specific Time

Tags: java, android, eclipse, time, notifications

I Want To Notify When Even The Time Is 7:30.
I Couldn't manage to do that with a while loop
for exp:

```
while(stop != false){
textViewSecs.setText(String.ValueOf(secs));
textViewMin.setText(String.ValueOf(min));
textViewHour.setText(String.ValueOf(Hour));
if(hour == 7 && min == 30)
notify.show();
```

Any Toughts Or Ideas how to update the textView and notify when its 7:30?

Comment: AlarmManager is what you need. Google it

Comment: Ok thanks but if i want to change the value of those TextViews To the current time,one to the seconds,one to the min,one to the hour,

Comment: Google it too :) The time your AlarmManager will hit you receiver.

Comment: Havnt Found a good example for the good tought i did understood how its done,can you send me a good example?